# How to read in multiple floats on one line and then add them to an array?

Tags: c, floating-point, extract, c-strings, fgets

I am trying to read in a line of floating point values like

```
1.1 -100.0 2.3
```

and I need to store these in an array.
I am using the `fgets()` method to convert the input into a string. Is there anyway I can use this string to populate a float array with the values? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char input [500];
    float values [50];
    fgets(input, 500, stdin);
// now input has a string with all the values
// and the values array needs to be filled with the values
}
```

Comment: Use `strtok()` to split the input string, then call `atof()` to convert each one to a `float`.

Comment: If it is always exactly a fixed/known number of floats then can also use `sscanf`.

Comment: Amending @kaylum's suggestion: [`sscanf`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/)

Comment: For a tutorial, see [these class notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10h.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `sscanf` for the inputted string.

Here is a simplified demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char input[20];
    float values[3];
    
    fgets( input, sizeof( input ), stdin );
    
    size_t n = 0;
    char *p = input;
    
    for ( int pos = 0; n < 3 && sscanf( p, "%f%n", values + n, &pos ) == 1; p += pos )
    {
        ++n;
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%.1f ", values[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return 0;
}
```

If the inputted string is

```
1.1 -100.0 2.3
```

then the output of the array `values` is

```
1.1 -100.0 2.3
```